# Building dynamic list in jquery and losing CSS

Tags: jquery, css, custom-lists

I am building a list of appointments by day and the appointments for the day are collapsible under the date header. I am using append to insert the list items. When the list is built dynamically, there is zero formatting. None of the jquery goodness or CSS shows through. Should I be building the list using a different method than append? The link below shows a static list built below a dynamic one.

http://www.roamingq.com/jquery/Test2.htm#my_qs

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Page Title</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#sayHelloButton").click(function (event) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'http://www.roamingq.com/rqes/rqservice.svc/Test',
                        //url: 'http://www.roamingq.com/rqes/user.svc/Authenticate',
                        data: {},
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        processdata: true,
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert(result.d);
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            alert("failure");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });      
        </script>-->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            $(function () {
                $(".submit").click(function () {
                    var email = $("#lgn_email").val();
                    var password = $("#lgn_password").val();
                    var dataString = 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password;
                    alert(dataString);
                    return false;
                });
            });
</script>
    </head> 
<body> 


<!-- Start of Login -->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="login">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-nobackbtn="true">
        <h1>Mobile Q Login</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-inset="true">
        <form id="target" method="post" action="#my_qs">
            <fieldset>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="lgn_email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="lgn_email" id="lgn_email" value=""  />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="lgn_password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="lgn_password" id="lgn_password" value="" />
                </div>
                <p>
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="lgn_rememberme" id="lgn_rememberme" class="custom" data-theme="c" />
                        <label for="lgn_rememberme">Remember me</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </p>
                    <a href="#my_qs" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Login</a>
                <!--<input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit"/>-->
                <!--<input id="sayHelloButton" value="Say Hello" type="button" />-->
                <p>Don't have an account? <a href="#registration">Register</a> now for free!</p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Login -->









<!-- Start of Registration -->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="registration">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-nobackbtn="true">
        <h1>Mobile Q Registration</h1>
        <!--<a href="#login" class="ui-btn-right">Cancel</a>-->
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-inset="true">
        <form action="/FormActions/register.ashx" method="get">
            <fieldset>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="rg_mobileNumber">Mobile #:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="rg_mobileNumber" id="rg_mobileNumber" value=""  />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="rg_firstName">First name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="rg_firstName" id="rg_firstName" value=""  />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="rg_lastName">Last name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="rg_lastName" id="rg_lastName" value=""  />
                </div>                
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="rg_email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="rg_email" id="rg_email" value=""  />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="rg_password1">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="rg_password1" id="rg_password1" value="" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="rg_password2">Re-enter Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="rg_password2" id="rg_password2" value="" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <p>By submitting this information, I acknowledge that I have
                    read and agree to the <a href='MobileQ_TermsofUse.DOC.html' data-rel=”dialog” rel="external" data-transition=”flip”>Terms of Use</a> and 
                    <a href='MobileQ_PrivacyPolicy.DOC.html' data-rel=”dialog” rel="external" data-transition=”pop”>Privacy Policy</a></p>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <a href="#my_qs" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Register</a>
                    <p>Already have an account? <a href="#login">Login</a></p>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Registration -->





<!-- Start of My Q's -->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="my_qs">
    <div data-role="header"  data-backbtn="false">
        <h1>Mobile Q</h1> 
        <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="top">My Q's</a></li>
            <li><a href="#new_q" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="top">New Q</a></li>
            <li><a href="#favorites" data-role="button" data-icon="star" data-rel="dialog"  data-transition="pop" data-iconpos="top">Favorites</a></li>
            <li><a href="#offers" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-iconpos="top">Offers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#settings" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-iconpos="top">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /header -->


    <div data-role="content" id="my_qs_listview">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://www.roamingq.com/rqes/user.svc/Authenticate',
                data: '{"User": "' + "bruce@roamingq.com" + '","Password": "' + "bru2bec" + '","BookingCategories": "' + "7" + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                processdata: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#my_qs_listview").append('<ul data-role="listview">');
                    $("#my_qs_listview").append('<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">');
                    $("#my_qs_listview").append('<h3>June 02, 2011</h3>');
                    $("#my_qs_listview").append('<ul data-role="listview">');
                    $.each(result.d.Reservations, function (i, Res) {
                        $("#my_qs_listview").append('<li><img src="icons/Service_55x55.png" style="vertical-align:middle;"/><h3>' + Res.Name + '</h3><p>' + Res.Address1 + '</p><p class="ui-li-aside"><b>' + Res.Detail + '</b></p>');
                    });
                    $("#my_qs_listview").append('</ul></div></ul>');
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert("Try again later.");
                }
            });
            $('#my_qs_listview').listview('refresh', true);
        });        
    </script>

</div>

    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" id="my_qs_listview">
        <h3>June 02, 2011</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li>
                <img src="icons/Fitness_55x55.png" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>
                <h3>Gold's Gym</h3>
                <p>Yoga Class</p>
                <p class="ui-li-aside"><b>6:30pm</b></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="icons/Service_55x55.png"/>
                <h3>Dale's Dead Bug</h3>
                <p>Exterior bug spraying</p>
                <p class="ui-li-aside"><b>ETA 2:15pm</b></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>



    <!--<div data-role="content" id="my_qs_listview">   
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
                <h3>June 02, 2011</h3>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>
                        <img src="icons/Fitness_55x55.png"  style="vertical-align:middle;"/>
                        <h3>Gold's Gym</h3>
                        <p>Yoga Class</p>
                        <p class="ui-li-aside"><b>6:30pm</b></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="icons/Service_55x55.png"/>
                        <h3>Dale's Dead Bug</h3>
                        <p>Exterior bug spraying</p>
                        <p class="ui-li-aside"><b>ETA 2:15pm</b></p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
                <h3>June 03, 2011</h3>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>
                        <img src="icons/Golf_55x55.png" />
                        <h3>Sleepy Ridge Golf</h3>
                        <p>18 holes + cart</p>
                        <p class="ui-li-aside"><b>8:00am</b></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="icons/Spas_55x55.png" />
                        <h3>Zen Spa</h3>
                        <p>60 minute massage</p>
                        <p class="ui-li-aside"><b>12:00pm</b></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="icons/Dentist_55x55.png" />
                        <h3>Dr Smith DDS</h3>
                        <p>Checkup and bleaching</p>
                        <p class="ui-li-aside"><b>1:30pm</b></p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
                <h3>June 04, 2011</h3>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>
                        <img src="icons/Salon_55x55.png" />
                        <h3>Super Salon</h3>
                        <p>Haircut and "Forever 41" tip frosting</p>
                        <p class="ui-li-aside"><b>4:00pm</b></p>
                    </li>                
                    <li>
                        <img src="icons/Restaurants_55x55.png" />
                        <h3>Tsunami</h3>
                        <p>Dinner reservation</p>
                        <p class="ui-li-aside"><b>7:30pm</b></p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>-->
</div>
<!-- End of My Q's -->





<!-- Start of New Q -->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="new_q">
    <div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false">
        <h1>Mobile Q</h1> 
        <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#my_qs" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="top">My Q's</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="top">New Q</a></li>
            <li><a href="#favorites" data-role="button" data-icon="star" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-iconpos="top">Favorites</a></li>
            <li><a href="#offers" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-iconpos="top">Offers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#settings" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-iconpos="top">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" style="height:20px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Select a New Q</div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <div class="ui-grid-b"> 
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#restaurants"><div style="height:120px; text-align:center;"><img src="icons/Restaurants_55x55.png" /><h5 >Restaurants</h5></div></a></div> 
            <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#salons"><div style="height:120px; text-align:center;"><img src="icons/Salon_55x55.png" /><h5 >Hair Salons</h5></div></a></div> 
            <div class="ui-block-c"><a href="#service"><div style="height:120px; text-align:center;"><img src="icons/Service_55x55.png" /><h5 >Service</h5></div></a></div> 
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#golf"><div style="height:120px; text-align:center;"><img src="icons/Golf_55x55.png" /><h5 >Golf</h5></div></a></div> 
            <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#spas"><div style="height:120px; text-align:center;"><img src="icons/Spas_55x55.png" /><h5 >Spas</h5></div></a></div> 
            <div class="ui-block-c"><a href="#dentists"><div style="height:120px; text-align:center;"><img src="icons/Dentist_55x55.png" /><h5 >Dentists</h5></div></a></div> 
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#fitness"><div style="height:120px; text-align:center;"><img src="icons/Fitness_55x55.png" /><h5 >Fitness</h5></div></a></div> 
            <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#rx"><div style="height:120px; text-align:center;"><img src="icons/RX_55x55.png" /><h5 >Pharmacies</h5></div></a></div> 
            <div class="ui-block-c"><a href="#general"><div style="height:120px; text-align:center;"><img src="icons/MQ_55x55.png" /><h5 >Dining</h5></div></a></div> 
        </div><!-- /grid-c -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
</div>
<!-- End of New Q -->

<!-- Start of Favorites page -->
<div data-role="page" id="favorites">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Favorites</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p>Come here to save time and book appointments at your bookmarked favorite restaurants, hair salons, golf courses, and more. </p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End of Favorites page -->


<!-- Start of Offers page -->
<div data-role="page" id="offers">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Offers</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p>This page will be updated with the hottest deals everywhere you like to go.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End of Offers page -->


<!-- Start of Settings page -->
<div data-role="page" id="settings">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Settings</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p>This screen is where you will change your geographical location, application preferences, etc.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End of Settings page -->


<!-- New Q's ----------------->
<!-- New Q's ----------------->
<!-- New Q's ----------------->
<!-- Restaurants -->
<div data-role="page" id="restaurants">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Restaurants</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p>Coming soon...</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Restaurants -->

<!-- Salons -->
<div data-role="page" id="salons">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Hair Salons</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p>Coming soon...</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Salons -->

<!-- Service -->
<div data-role="page" id="service">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Service Technicians</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p>Coming soon...</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Service -->

<!-- Golf -->
<div data-role="page" id="golf">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Golf Courses</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p>Coming soon...</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Golf -->

<!-- Spas -->
<div data-role="page" id="spas">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Spas</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p>Coming soon...</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Spas -->

<!-- Dentists -->
<div data-role="page" id="dentists">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Dentists</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p>Coming soon...</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Dentists -->

<!-- Fitness -->
<div data-role="page" id="fitness">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Fitness</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p>Coming soon...</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Fitness -->

<!-- RX -->
<div data-role="page" id="rx">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Pharmacies</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p>Coming soon...</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- RX -->




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expecting CSS and bindings which are applied by jquery mobile before page load.  Because you're creating additional DOM elements later you need to reinitialize the elements after append using

```
$('#something').append(data).trigger('create');
```

See the [JQM FAQs](http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html) for more.

I dug into your source **PLEASE POST YOUR OWN CODE!!** and it looks like  you've got other problems.  Jquery append doesn't work the way you think it does.  When you do this:

```
$("#my_qs_listview").append('<ul data-role="listview">');
$.each(result.d.Reservations, function (i, Res) {
    $("#my_qs_listview").append('<li>...');
});
```

The `UL` is closed before the `LIs` are appended and you get:

```
<ul data-role="listview"></ul>
<li>...</li>
...
```

When I assume what you want is:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li>...</li>
  ...    
</ul>
```

Build your string and then append the whole thing.  I recommend reading up on [append](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly).

Comment: So let me preface by saying that I am functionally almost smart enough to be stupid. But I went into firebug and added <li> list items on the fly with their elaborate css properties I saw in firebug and they rendered perfectly. I imagine you can see how I am reinventing the wheel and then adding corners so I can shave them off.

Comment: I don't follow you here.  Help us help you by posting your code :)

Comment: I think I uncovered a different kind of problem. I know how to use append, finally, but after I have created a dynamic list with an ajax call, the html appears correctly but with zero styling. I can try to strip code out of a static page and try and append with that but it is a nightmare. Any ideas of how to reapply specifically  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" /> after the ajax call?

Comment: I posted my code. I have figured out how/when to use .append, but it is weird that all styling is lost where I can create a list with zero styling and jquery gives it a default style.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that append() is fine, but you need to re-initialize collapsible after appending items so it can work all its magic.

```
$('#updated-element').collapsible('refresh');
```

Comment: I tried that, but adding an <li> with the css properties right there in the js loop worked. I know you are right, I just don't get why my method works. Especially since it is so inelegant.

Comment: By the way guys, thanks for all the help. I sincerely appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a CSS stylesheet and the jQuery addClass() method, the actual formatting should show through.

Since you are using jQuery to apply CSS to HTML elements after the webpage loads using

```
$(function(){
    //apply css to html elements
});
```

the dynamic list will not receive those CSS attributes. The elements haven't yet been written to the page and since the function runs after the page loads, your dynamic list will never receive those CSS attributes.

I would recommend creating a CSS stylesheet and then use the addClass() method specified here:

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/